# Nativescript Lazy loading not working inside Bottom Navigation

Tags: nativescript, lazy-loading, nativescript-angular

i started a new project with nativescript-angular (8.20.4). I'm facing an issue regarding the use of modules lazy loading. I managed to only get the first page (login) displayed using lazy loading. The bottom nav bar is displayed but the pages inside it are not loaded or displayed.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/login", pathMatch: "full" },
    //{ path: "", redirectTo: "/bottomnav", pathMatch: "full" },

    //{ path: "login", component: LoginComponent},
    { path: "login", loadChildren: () => import('./modules/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)},

    { path: "bottomnav", loadChildren: () => import('./modules/bottomnav/bottomnav.module').then(m => m.BottomnavModule)},
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
    exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
```

I probably forgot a declaration or something else but i can't figure it out.

The sample project is available on [github](https://github.com/npmnewbie/ns-bottomnav-withlogin/) : https://github.com/npmnewbie/ns-bottomnav-withlogin/

**bottomnav-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "bottomnav", pathMatch: "full" },

  { path: "bottomnav", redirectTo: "/(browse:browse//search:search)", pathMatch: "full" },

  { 
    path: "browse", 
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent, 
    outlet: "browse", loadChildren: () => import('../browse/browse.module').then(m => m.BrowseModule)
  },

  { 
    path: "search", 
    component: NSEmptyOutletComponent, 
    outlet: "search" , loadChildren: () => import('../search/search.module').then(m => m.SearchModule)
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild([{path: "", component: BottomnavComponent, children: routes}]),],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule]
})
export class BottomnavRoutingModule { }
```

**bottomnav.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({

  declarations: [BottomnavComponent],
  imports: [
    BottomnavRoutingModule,
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
  ],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class BottomnavModule { }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

[Image Login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmmW8.png)

[Image Tab nav bar empty page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zjay.png)

Edit : my project is based on [playground based project](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=U4Rmr9&v=2&_ga=2.9203376.426259476.1580149554-2128206889.1580149554)

Comment: `redirectTo: "/(browse:browse//search:search)"` is unfamiliar syntax to me. Are you sure this is what you meant?

Comment: I based my project on the playground sample (https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=U4Rmr9&v=2&_ga=2.9203376.426259476.1580149554-2128206889.1580149554)

Comment: The redirectTo syntax is used in the playground project.

Comment: I don't think multiple redirects will work - you seem to be redirecting to bottomnav and from there you are redirecting again.

Comment: Same result if i comment the redirectTo.

Comment: Please share your project as Playground.

Comment: i have got same problem. Did you found solution?